# Does differentiability in an open interval imply continuity at end points?

Tags: real-analysis

It is well known that "differentiability at a point implies continuity at that point". I am thinking about the following proposition:

> A function $f: \left[a,b\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable over the open interval $\left(a,b\right)$, then it is continuous at $a$ and $b$.

Intuitively, I cannot think of a counter example for this proposition. Can anyone provide a proof or hints for a proof?

Comment: There are very simple counterexamples, since you can change $f(a)$ and/or $f(b)$ to whatever you like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$$
defined by

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\; if \; 0<x<1$$
and

$$f(0)=f(1)=0$$

$ f $ is clearly differentiable at $ (0,1)$ with
$$(\forall x\in(0,1))\;\;f'(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x^2(1-x)^2}$$
but not continuous neither at $ 0 $ nor at $ 1$.

Comment: This is a very simple question, but I have been thinking how properties of a whole open area do not affect its nearest point. This is strange.

Answer (score 4):

Your proposition is wrong. Differentiability in the interior does not give you anything at the boundary. Consider, for example $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbf R$ with
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \{a,b\}\\ 1 & x \in (a,b) \end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is even analytic on $(a,b)$ but not continuous at $a$ and $b$.